# No puedo debuggear archivo .cpp en WSL | Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, vscode, wsl

Estoy codeando con WSL, cuando trato de debuggear me salta primero esta ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando doy a "debug anyway" me salta esta otra ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo debuggear sin este problema en WSL?
Aqui les dejo mis .json

**launch.json**

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

**settings.json**

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "iostream": "cpp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Parece que ocurre algún error a la hora de compilar el código. Asegúrate de que tienes gcc instalado. Toca el botón **Show Errors** e incluye la información adicional en la pregunta.